# ASP.net method that returns a control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a method that returns a DropDownList control. In the calling page, I create a new DropDownList in CodeBehind, set it to the returning value of the method, then DataBind(). I consistently get an empty DropDownList.

```
public static DropDownList GetDropDownList()
 {

        DropDownList ddlInstance = new DropDownList();
        ddlInstance.DataSource = [METHOD THAT RETURNS DATATABLE]
        ddlInstance.DataTextField = ["COLUMN FROM TABLE";]
        ddlInstance.DataValueField = ["ANOTHER COLUMN FROM TABLE";]
        ddlInstance.DataBind();

        return ddlInstance;

 }
```

and then in the CodeBehind of the page...

```
DropDownListOnPage = GetDropDownList();
DropDownListOnPage.DataBind();
```

Can anyone spot any problems here that might be causing the DropDownList on the page to not show any data?

Comment: You should really don't let the method return the fully loaded dropdown, but instead let it just return the data. Then: `DropDownListOnPage.DataSource = GetDataSource(); ... DropDownListOnPage.DataBind();`

Comment: Why not? Are you saying it's bad practice or it doesn't work?

Comment: I have a need to reuse this control repeatedly and it would be great to just get the fully-loaded control instead of constantly setting its DataTextField and DataValueField.