# Set GridView control to a method that returns GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to set my ASP.net GridView control to my [GridView GetGridView()] method (which returns a GridView) but I don't think this works.  It didn't work on DropDown List control using the same pattern.

I read the following, the OP's question about whether it's not possible or just best practice wasn't really answered.
[ASP.net method that returns a control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25344450/asp-net-method-that-returns-a-control)

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //sets the ASP Gridview control to a method that returns a GridView control
    LoadGvUsersTemplate();
    if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            //adds Columns in the Gridview
            gvUsers = _GvTemplateAccess.AddUserColumns(gvUsers); 
            //sets gvUsers to a DataSource
            LoadGvUserData(); 
            //Binds the data //Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object
            gvUsers.DataBind(); 
        }
    }

private void LoadGvUsersTemplate()
{ 
    //returns a setup Gridview with specific columns            
    gvUsers = _GvTemplateAccess.GetGvTemplateUser(); 
}

private void LoadGvUserData() 
{
    UserAccessLayer userdb = new UserAccessLayer();
    int searchType = ddlSearchType.SelectedIndex;
    string searchTerm = txtSearchTerm.Text.ToString();
    gvUsers.DataSource = userdb.getUsers(searchType, searchTerm);
}
```

I get an Error Message=

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

on `gvUsers.DataBind()` instead of seeing populated GridView, which doesn't tell me much.
But seeing as how setting my ASP DropDownList to a method that returns DropDownList also didn't work, I think it's either not possible to set an ASP control to a method in general or I'm missing the way to do this properly.

Comment: Don't try to set a gridview to a method, just call the method: not `gvUsers = _GvTemplateAccess.AddUserColumns(gvUsers);`, just `_GvTemplateAccess.AddUserColumns(gvUsers);`.

Comment: Mainly, make sure gvUsers exists.